# How to pass distances to Multiple Ring Buffer in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I want to use Multiple Ring Buffer in ModelBuilder however I'm not able to pass it 'distances' values. It only accepts one block with a single double value. It's not accepting a list of double values or a string with separated values.

How to pass multiple 'distances' values to Multiple Ring buffer script?

EDIT for PolyGeo:

The model is really trivial:
[image]

As long as the distances block is a single double value I'm able to connect it to the script, if it's something else, it doesn't allow me to connect it as Distances. The script itself uses convertValueTableToList function on the entered value. However I can't find an appropriate block with ValueTable type.

Comment: What version of ArcGIS for Desktop are you using?  I just tested using ArcGIS 10.1 SP1 and was able to get multiple values entered just by right clicking on the Multiple Ring Buffers tool in the model and making Distances a parameter.  I have a vague idea this came in at 10.1.

Comment: @PolyGeo I wasn't clear enough. I want to create a variable block (is that how you should call these things?) with distances and connect this block to the multiple ring buffer block. I don't have any trouble entering the values by hand. I load them from a DB and that's why I have them in block form.

Comment: I think I will need to see a diagram before I can try to help.  I think the term to search on is "multivalue input" but I've not used Multiple Ring Buffer in ModelBuilder or Python so I'll be learning along the way.

Comment: @PolyGeo I've updated the question.

Comment: How does the model read in the values from the DB? Can you post a sample of the input values you have tried to use?

Comment: @danb To be honest I haven't connected them yet to this model since I'm having trouble using Multiple Ring Buffer script, at the moment I mock them with a variable block.

Comment: @Michal, are all the  your buffer distances in a single column?

Comment: @danb Single column of what type representation?

Comment: @Michal. int/double. Can you post a snapshot of your data as it is in your DB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your buffer distances are stored in a table like this:

[image]

You can use the [Collect Values](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Collect_Values/004000000005000000/) tool in model builder to create a list of values to pass to the Multiple Ring buffer tool.

Set up your nested models like this:

**Main Model**

[image]

**Sub Model**

The sub model iterates through your input table and collects the values and passes them up with acceptable formatting for the Multiple Ring buffer tool. Set the **Distance column** as the group field in the iterator.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will check it tomorrow, when I'm back at work.